# How to subtract a year from the datetime?

Tags: c#

How to subtract a year from current datetime using c#?

Answer (score 223, accepted):

```
var myDate = DateTime.Now;
var newDate = myDate.AddYears(-1);
```

Comment: Thanks. One another related question - how to subtract week?

Answer (score 51):

```
DateTime oneYearAgoToday = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
```

Subtracting a week:

```
DateTime weekago = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
```

Answer (score 10):

It might be worth noting that the accepted answer may adjust the date by either 365 days or 366 days due to leap years (it gets the date for the same day of the month one year ago, with the exception of 29th February where it returns 28th February).

In the vast majority of cases this is exactly what you want however if you are treating a year as a fixed unit of time (e.g. [the Julian year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_year_(astronomy))) then you would need to subtract from either days;

```
        var oneFullJulianYearAgo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-365.25);
```

or seconds;

```
        var oneFullJulianYearAgo = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-31557600);
```