# How to Insert year before's date in textbox

Tags: c#, datetime

I have to 2 textbox, fromdate and todate. I have to insert today's date in todate textbox and in fromdate textbox have to insert date before 2 year. How can I do that ?

```
    DateTime todate = DateTime.Today;
    string TodateString = todate.ToString();
    string fromdate ;
    //from date = todate - 2 years
    todatetextbox.Text = todate;
    fromdatetextbox.Text = fromdate;
```

how can I minus 2 years from current year ?

Comment: have you tried  `DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2)` ?

Answer (score 3):

`date = myDate.AddYears(-2);`

Source: [How to subtract a year from the datetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992451/how-to-subtract-a-year-from-the-datetime)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `Year` and a simple mathematical operation::

```
        DateTime todate = DateTime.Today;
        int year2 = todate.Year-2;
        string DesiredYear = year2.ToString();
```