# How to subtract a year and a day from the datetime?

Tags: c#, datetime

I see the answer like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2992457/3159849)  but how to add 1 day after this? Like 2 years ago and 1 day.

```
var myDate = DateTime.Now;
var newDate = myDate.AddYears(-2);
var NewExpiryDate = myDate.AddDays(-1);
var NewFinalDate = ?
```

Comment: You need to `AddDays` to `newDate`, not `myDate`. `var NewExpiryDate = newDate.AddDays(-1);`. The last line is not needed at all. Alternatively, you can write `var date = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).AddDays(-1);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are doing wrong:

`myDate` will be the current date then you add `-2` years with the current date and assign to `newDate`. Which will not update the `myDate` it's still the current date, so you need to add `-1` days to the `newDate` to get the required output. A more simple way you can use like this:

```
var newDate = myDate.AddYears(-2).AddDays(-1);
```

> **Note :** The date Functions [`.AddYears()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addyears(v=vs.110).aspx) will not alter the source, it will return a new DateTime that adds the specified number
>   of years to the value of this instance.
>   As Soner said, `DateTime` is an immutable type Which means is an object whose state cannot be modified after it is created.

Comment: Yeah, that's because `DateTime` is immutable type. You _can't_ change them. Even if you think you change them, you _actually_ create a new `DateTime` instance.

Comment: Wow!!! It solve my problem. All queries now is getting a two year and 1 day less. Thank you :)

Comment: @down-Voter : appreciate the spirit and thanks for the support. This is an open community not the Place to show Personal revenge.